# Unyson demo importer invalid resource directory

Tags: php, wordpress

When I install my demo content using Unyson thay give me error.

[image]

I follow below documentations

[Unysong Docs](http://manual.unyson.io/en/latest/extension/backups/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i found my solution my self 
>   problem is it if we use unyson demo data
>   importer than we must backup by unyson extension. else we can't
>   import data by unyson demo importer.

thanks.
 all of you.